# Water under the vapour barrier in the attic

Tags: attic

I noticed a small wet patch on my bathroom ceiling. So I climbed into the attic to see if the roof is leaking as the wet patch was close to the wall near where the eves trough runs. It was then that I noticed that there was a little bit of water under the vapour barrier. I have no idea how it got in there. Any suggestions on what I could do .Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just the fact that you mention a vapor barrier in your attic is the problem. Attics should never have vapor barriers.

Only walls. Next time your at your local home improvement store look at the insulation. You'll see insulation for attics is unfaced and wall insulation has a kraft face, though you can install an unfaced wall insulation if planning on adding a vapor barrier.

Homes will always have moisture and it's through the attic that that moisture needs to escape. That is why your finding the moisture UNDER the barrier.

Comment: Bingo. Take that thing out before it ruins your ceilings!

Comment: Wrong.  At least contrary to code here.  From the bottom up, a typical ceiling roof here has  Paint -> drywall -> vapour barrier -> Truss.  Then between and above the bottom cord 12-18" of loose fill insulation.  All joints in the plastic are taped, all intrusions airtight.

Comment: If you are finding moisture under the barrier, then your attic isn't properly insulated, and the vapour barrier was not carefully installed.  Water vapour is getting into that space and is condensing at a cold spot.

I have seen one house where the bath fan wasn't detailed properly, so it was pumping water vapour into the atttic space.

Answer (score 1):

Condensation. Put in a more effective exhaust/ventilation fan. Or just remove the
vapor barrier and let your poor bathroom breathe.